Unique continuation for $\operatorname{div}(a_{ij} \nabla u)$ with $ a _{ij} \in W^{1,d}$
Let $\Omega$ be a connected domain in $\mathbf{R}^d$, with $d>2$. Assume that $ A(x)=(a _{ij})_{1 \leq i,j \leq d}$ is uniformly positive definite, with variable coefficients in $ W^{1,d}(\Omega)$.  Does anyone know if the second-order elliptic operator $\operatorname{div}(A(x) \nabla u)$ has the unique continuation property?
